# Why is it necessary for "input()" to be at the end of the line ? Or is it?

Tags: python, input, variable-assignment, python-3.9

I started my first course on udemy with the Automate things with python course. And it started with us writing a little script that asks us our name and age et c. Ok. So, when they have us write the code, it has us put in 2 separate lines that say "name = input()" and "age = input()" So it prompts the user to put in their name and age.

So my question is why will it not work if I reverse the order and say "input() = name" and "input() = age"?  I thought that logically it would want to read the "input()" function first so it knows its about to ask the user something. Why is it this way? Will I always have to make sure my "input()" is at the end of the line and not at the beginning?

sorry in advance, im only just starting to learn. (also i have latest version of 64bit windows python.) 3.9.2 i think

edit: i now realize this is considered off-topic. if im supposed to delete it, just let me know.

Comment: Assignment syntax in general is `destination = new_value`. You can't run `42 = whatever` in Python either -- only `whatever = 42` will work.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements for the formal definition of what constitutes an assignment in Python. `(target_list "=")` being at the beginning means that the targets of the assignment (the things being assigned to) **must** be before the `=`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ok thank you, that makes sense now.

Comment: That said, note that "why" questions about language design are generally considered off-topic here. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170415/144918

Answer (score 1):

It nearly all programming languages, undirected variable assignment (the use of an equal sign `=`) occurs left to right, with the variable on the left side and the value on the right.  To create a variable `x` and assign its value to be 1, you use:

```
x = 1
```

Some languages, such as R, support directed variable assignment.  If you want to assign x to `1` using right-ward assignment you can use:

```
1 -> x
```

There is no equivalent of this in Python.  It is just not how the language is constructed.

When using `input`, calling the `input` function prompts the user for a value, captures the value and then assigns it to the variable.  For this to occur, the variable must be on the left side of the equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how the language works (and how really most language assignments work).

You can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) the full grammar specification for the language. Relevant here is the assignment specification:

```
assignment:
    | NAME ':' expression ['=' annotated_rhs ] 
    | ('(' single_target ')' 
         | single_subscript_attribute_target) ':' expression ['=' annotated_rhs ] 
    | (star_targets '=' )+ (yield_expr | star_expressions) !'=' [TYPE_COMMENT] 
    | single_target augassign ~ (yield_expr | star_expressions)
```

It's a bit hard to read. The important parts for here though boil down to essentially:

```
NAME = expression
```

The right hand side of `=` is an expression that evaluates to a value. The name on the left hand side is the name that the data should be associated with.

For your example, `input()` is an expression that evaluates to a value, and `name` is the name to associate with that value.

Answer (score 0):

In most programming language if not all you declear the variable name before you assign any other thing to it that is why input() cannot come first because it is a function. you have to declear the variable before you assign any thing to it